# Enviar mensaje a whatsapp desde php

Tags: php, javascript, android, whatsapp, mensajes

Holaaaa, tengo la siguiente situación, quiero que llegue automáticamente un mensaje al whatsapp de varios numeros guardados en mi base de datos, tengo la posibilidad de que esos números me tengan agregado en su whatsapp (si fuera necesario). Quiero saber si eso se puede hacer con php o javascript, o si siquiera es posible hacerlo de algún modo, talvez controlando mi propia whatsapp con algún software que haga que envie mensajes automáticamente a todos los números guardados en mi base de datos, o alguna forma de conseguirlo por medio de un código que pueda poner en mi web.

Comment: Si que existe una forma, puesto que la presencie yo mismo mediante el tio de un amigo el cual me mostro en vivo como es que al mandar un mensaje desde la aplicacion de mensajeria por default de cualquier telefono y al subscribirte a un servicio podias enviar mensajes o recibirlos por whatsapp, sin embargo seguro pensaras que no esta ligado, la verdad es que creo firmemente que si que hay forma de hacerlo pero desde javascript y no desde la app de mensajeria por default de un celular, sin embargo el inconveniente principal son dos cosas.

Comment: El primer problema es que la forma en la que habia visto del como se realizaba esa accion era por un `<intent>` es decir que solo funcionaria para apps moviles (deberas crear una app para movil usando javascript (se puede por ejemplo usando un framework llamado `ionic`), lo segundo es que el intent debe apuntar a abrir la app de whatsapp la cual te permitira dar la autorizacion necesaria para enviar el mensaje por medio de whatsapp, el segundo problema es que esta forma solo servira para contactos que tu tengas agregados en whatsapp, mas no los de tu base de datos.

Comment: No se si habran formas de hacerlo directamente desde el pc o una web, pero yo creo fielmente en que si, sin embargo para la web la verdad es que no tengo ni idea de como se haria.

Comment: De todas maneras ahora que he dicho todo esto, permiteme darte la bienvenida al sitio, de acuerdo a tu pregunta hay que decir que segun las normas de la comunidad tu pregunta no es valida, por lo que lo primero que te recomendaria hacer como usuario nuevo es pasar por el [tour] y leer [ask], para poder que puedas realizar mejores preguntas a futuro, o en caso de que leas el apartado de [ask] tambien puedes si quieres editar la pregunta que haz hecho y colocar todo lo necesario para que tu pregunta sea valida para una respuesta.

Comment: Según tengo entendido con el API de WhatsApp Business se puede hacer lo que mencionas, quizá este link te pueda resultar útil https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides

Comment: No veo ningún ejemplo de código en esa página para poder enviar mensaje a un número de whatsapp mediante php o javascript, no entiendo nada

Comment: La respuesta directa a tu pregunta seria.... No, no puedes hacerlo desde la web en este caso la web de un PC, Sorry no podia comentar

Comment: @ArturoRodas, el que busca encuentra... si no código, al menos información de _API de administración_ y de ahí todo lo que necesites, solo siguiendo las instrucciones.

Comment: Podrías probar con el servicio de Twilio, sólo que ojo no admite envío de spam.

Answer (score 0):

lo mismo que quieres hacer tu me lo propuse unas cuantas semanas atras, pero me encontré con que no había una forma formal de hacer esto, no podía utilizar y manipular a mi antojo el link de enviar mensaje.

Ahora bien, hay una opción que te da whatsapp y que con la cual debes tener experiencia en `API REST` y `.json` para poder desarrollar una web en php que te permita enviar mensajes desde tu código php a cualquier usuario de tu libreta de contactos, te recomiendo entrar en : https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api

ahí podras ver toda la Documentación para el desarrollo de la `API`, es la única forma posible de hacerlo, Saludos.